# How to get the desired output data to determine treatment pattern?

Tags: sql, sas

I am having problem to create the desired output data in sas.

I have to indentify the drugs which has been used in first 21 days and it will create initial line of treatment .but the below rules are applied to finalize the  line of treatment.

The start date will be first use of any drug irrespective of core or no core

The end date will be last end date of last use of any core drug

If any core drug from initial line of treatment is found within 60 days from the end date of initial line of treatment then the end of initial line of treatment would be updated to end date of this indentified core drug. Again i have to check for 60 days gap and so on.

If a new core drug is identified (other than the core drug from initial line of treatment) before the end date of initial lot first lot will end one day before the start date of new core drug .Second line of treatment will be started from the start date of new core drug.

If there is no core drug from initial lot of treatment within 60 days of the end date of initial line of treatment, then second line of treatment will be started and the same above rule will be applied to find third or subsequent lots.
If there is any overlapping case like a core drug C1 is continue some days after starting of second line of treatment and it is again found any time after start of second line of treatment then the second line of treatment would contain the drugs from second line of treatment along with c1 .The end date will be the end of latest use of any core drug.

Data I have

```
patient_id         drug_name       drug_type      start           end

A11                            N1               Non_core       23-Apr-14   21-May-14

A11                        C1                 Core         27-Apr-14   25-May-14

A11                        C1                 Core         3-May-14   31-May-14

A11                        N1               Non_core   10-May-14   7-Jun-14

A11                        C2                  Core        11-May-14    8-Jun-14

A11                        N2               Non_core   12-May-14    9-Jun-14

A11                        C1                 Core         10-Jul-14      7-Aug-14

A11                        C1                 Core         15-Jul-14    12-Aug-14

A11                        C3                 Core         29-Jul-14     26-Aug-14

A11                        N4              Non_core     8-Sep-14       6-Oct-14

A11                        N2              Non_core     9-Sep-14      7-Oct-14

A11                        C1                Core           12-Sep-14    10-Oct-14

A11                        C1                Core           15-Sep-14    13-Oct-14

A11                        C1                Core           27-Sep-14     25-Oct-14

A11                        C3                Core            1-Jan-15        29-Jan-15

A11                        C1                 Core           3-Jan-15       31-Jan-15

A11                        C1                 Core            5-Jan-15       2-Feb-15

A11                        C1                 Core           10-Jan-15      7-Feb-15

A11                        N1              Non_core       15-Jan-15    12-Feb-15

A11                        N2              Non_core       18-Jan-15     15-Feb-15
```

Data I want

```
patient_id           drug                       start               end             lot

A11                 C1+N1+C2+N2       23-Apr-14      28-Jul-14        1

A11                  C3+C1+N4+N2      29-Jul-14       25-Oct-14        2

A11                 C3+C1+N1+N2        1-Jan-15       15-Feb-15       3
```

Here lot represents line of treatment

In this data initially drugs found in first 21days are N1,c1,c1,n1,c2,n2 and the initial start date of lot 1 will be 4/23/2014 and initial end date will be the latest  use of any core drug which is 6/8/2014

Next I need to check if there is any core drug from initial lot is available within 60 days of end of initial lot . c1 from lot 1 is there within 60 days .so the new end date will be updated to 8/7/2014.Again I have to look for 60 days criteria. i found again c1 is available within 60 days. So the new end date would be 8/12/2014.But as per the rule above  there is a new core drug(other than the core drugs from initial lot) available before the end of initial line of treatment .so the first line of treatment will be end one day before the start date of newly indentified core drug. Then end of first lot is 7/28/2014.

Second line of treatment starts at 7/29/2014.the same above rules are applied here also to determine to end date .the drugs found in 21 days are C3, C1, N4, N2,C1.The initial end date will be 10/13/2014.There is an overlapping drug (C1) from lot 1 because latest use of C1 is 8/7/2014 which is after start of second lot and it is found again any time after start of lot 2.Then end date of second lot would be 10/25/2014.

As there is no drug found within 6o days so end of second lot, third lot will start at 1/1/2015.Same rule as above will be applied .

I have tried the below code but it is not giving the desired output.It is giving the below output.

patient_id  start_date  end_date    drug    lot

A11        27-Apr-14    11-May-14   C1+N1+C2    1

A11        10-Jul-14    8-Sep-14    C1+C3   2

A11        12-Sep-14    26-Sep-14   C1  3

A11 1-Jan-15    17-Jan-15   C3+C1+C1    4

```
data want (keep=patient_id drug start_date end_date lot);
  set have;
  by patient_id;
  retain start_date end_date drug end60;
  format start_date end_date date9.;
  set have ( firstobs = 2 keep = start drug_type drug_name 
              rename = (start = next_start drug_type=next_type drug_name=next_drug) )
      have (      obs = 1 drop = _all_ );
  next_start = ifn(last.patient_id, (.), next_start );
  if first.patient_id or counter eq 0 then do;
    start_date=start;
    end_date=end;
    if drug_type eq 'Core' then do;
      counter=1;
      drug=drug_name;
      end60=end+60;
    end;
    else do;
      drug='';
      counter=0;
    end;
  end;
  else if start le Start_Date+21 then do;
    if counter=0 then do;
      if drug_type eq 'Core' then do;
        drug=drug_name;
        counter=1;
        end60=end;
      end;
    end;
    else do;
      if not findw(drug,drug_name) then drug=catx('+',drug,drug_name);
      if drug_type eq 'Core' then do;
        counter+1;
        end_date=end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  else if Start_Date le end60 and findw(drug,drug_name) and drug_type eq 'Core' then do;
    end60=end+60;
  end;
  if counter gt 0 and
     (next_start gt End60 or
     (counter gt 0 and
      not findw(drug,next_drug) and
      next_type eq 'Core' and
      next_start gt start_date+21)) or
      last.patient_id then do;
    end_date=start-1;
    lot+1;
    output;
    drug='';
    core='';
    counter=0;
  end;
run;
```

Any leads would be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a LOT of logic, which honestly I didn't read all of.  I suggest you post the code you have tried, and the output it gives, and then point to the disappointments/surprises in the output.  Understanding your code may be easier than understanding the full logic. Especially if you have code that is close to working like you want.

Comment: which sql database? and are you able to post the create script regards

Comment: I have added the code which I tried.

Comment: I think this is too much for a SO question. If you can narrow it down to one question at a time you're likely to get better responses. I do understand that it's a big process, but for someone not working with this type of data day in/day out it will be difficult to understand and I used to do that ;)